# javascript pass post data from one form to another

Tags: jquery, html, forms, google-maps

What I am trying to make it happen is there are two pages with very silimar forms, user can enter an address in index.php, once select the address from autocomplete list, it will automatically redirect to test.php and pass the value to the other form then automatically hit on 'submit'. Also user can go to test.php directly and submit from there.

But seems even I put `action="test.php"` `method="get"` it will redirect and show in the url but nothing happens.

Index.php

```
<script>
      function initialize() {
      var input =(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);      

      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function   () {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    console.log(place);
                    //Ridirect_url += place.value();
                    //window.location.href = Redirect_url;
                });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="Test.php" method="get">
<input id="pac-input"  name="FindAddress" type="text" placeholder="Enter a   location">
</form>     
</body>
```

Test.php

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert(document.getElementById("myForm").value);
        }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="myForm"  name="testAddress" type="text" placeholder="Enter a    location">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really using PHP, then I guess what you missed is 
`<?php echo $_GET["FindAddress"]; ?>`, which should make you code in Test.php looks like

```
<input id="myForm"  name="testAddress" type="text" placeholder="Enter a    location" value="<?php echo $_GET["FindAddress"]; ?>">
```

However, if you are not running this on a PHP server, then you can still get your URL parameters from the URL using Javascript (since you are using get)

You can use something like [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

or write your own Javascript to do it.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Thanks man, I can redirect in both ways(javascript and php). happy! do you know how to automatically hit on the submit button on the Test.php page after redirect.